# Some columns in Interactive Grid didn't exported using apex_region.export_data APEX API function

Tags: oracle-apex

I created an interactive Grid using this SQL Query:

```
select
    REGISTERATION_ID,
    STUDENT_ID,
    DRIVER_ID,
    DELIVERY_TYPE,
    PAYMENT_TYPE,
    AMOUNT,
    CURRENCY,
    DISCOUNT_TYPE,
    DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,
    NET_AMOUNT,
    START_DATE,
    END_DATE,
    PAID_AMOUNT,
    UNPAID_AMOUNT
from myTable
```

Now I want to export data of this Grid using the `apex_region.export_data` API function:

```
l_export := apex_region.export_data (
    p_format       => apex_data_export.c_format_json,
    p_as_clob      => true,  
    p_page_id      => 620,
    p_region_id    => no_of_region_id,
    p_data_only    => true);
v_clob_json_items := l_export.content_clob;
```

the json object returned in v_clob_json_items is the following:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "student_id": "student_name_of_select_list_item_with_value_id",
            "start_date": "2023-05-30T00:00:00",
            "end_date": "2023-07-12T00:00:00",
            "driver_id": "driver_name_of_select_list_item",
            "delivery_type": "\u0630\u0647\u0627\u0628 \u0648\u0625\u064A\u0627\u0628",
            "net_amount": 12000,
            "payment_type": "\u0623\u0633\u0628\u0648\u0639\u064A",
            "paid_amount": 0,
            "unpaid_amount": 12000
        },
        {
            "student_id": "student_name_of_select_list_item_with_value_id",
            "start_date": "2023-01-31T00:00:00",
            "end_date": "2023-05-29T00:00:00",
            "driver_id": "driver_name_of_select_list_item",
            "delivery_type": "\u0630\u0647\u0627\u0628 \u0648\u0625\u064A\u0627\u0628",
            "net_amount": 40000,
            "payment_type": "\u0634\u0647\u0631\u064A",
            "paid_amount": 40000,
            "unpaid_amount": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect that **CURRENCY** column exported some values, its select list item contain currencies values and names. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure that the column you'd like to be exported has the column attribute "Include in export/print" enabled?[image]